# Porting Angular to DJango Web (1.0) style: Calling functions from Django Template

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I am new to django and the task I need to accomplish is a port of AngularJs to an old school web 1.0 django application (for older browsers). There is one unknown I am dealing with and that are functions associated with $scope in angular.  I don't know how to replicate that logic in Django.

An example would be (in angular):

```
<div ng-show="isAuthorizedAs('Administrator')"></div>
```

And then in the controller:

```
$scope.isAuthorizedAs = function(functionalRole) {
     if($scope.user.role == 'basic'){
        if(functionalRole == 'basic') return true
     }
     else if($scope.user.role == 'advanced'){
        if(functionalRole == 'basic') return true
        if(functionalRole == 'advanced') return true
     }
     else if($scope.user.role == 'administrator'){
        if(functionalRole == 'basic') return true
        if(functionalRole == 'advanced') return true
        if(functionalRole == 'administrator') return true
     }

     return false
}
```

The gist is that the controller  either has complex logic (that works on one model or multiple models) OR special formatting.  I realize that these may be non-optimal use-cases AND that the above javascript function leaves a lot to be desired- but both objectives are in my direct path of execution.

My goal is to build this functionality out within a week - and don't want t deviate much from the AngularJs templates/application.  Therefore I am willing to concede a non-optimal solution for my delivery - and then to reconsider at a future date.

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? You can always check if a user is admin in controller or even have a model method for that. Current user object is always available to template. You can just check and show that div. That's the standard procedure for a web framework. Even Angular is doing that. that `ng-show` is not magic. It has the same workflow behind it. What are you looking for?

Comment: HOW from the django framework can I call a custom function.  Above is one use case but there are many.  I am asking how this is done within django?  Do I need to stick the functions in an object and pass that to the renderer?  Is there another method?  WHat is the best way?

Comment: TBH, sounds like to me that you didn't even try to do it in Django.

Comment: It is not a question o trying to do it - see the example you posted below - it skirts the question. I want to be able to call a function that is located outside of the template AND not associated with a model in order to perform the check.  I posted a single example but I have many that will be easiest to follow the existing pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is. What you're looking for is to check if the logged in user is an admin and if so render a part of the template. It's one of the basic things you learn while learning Django. Still, here is how you can achieve the above scenario.

I have no idea what your user model looks like as you have not mentioned it. So I'm assuming your user model has a field called `role` which can be set to either `basic`, `advanced` and `administrator`. Now when you login to Django, the current logged in user object is available in the template inside a variable called `user`, provided you have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings in `settings.py`.

Then in the template you can just do this -

```
{% if user.role == 'administrator' %}
<div class="secret_div">
    Super Secret Information Here
</div>
{% endif %}
```

If your user model doesn't have any such field and you have some other ways of checking if the user is admin, you can add a method to the user object by subclassing the default `User` class or creating your own User model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    # more fields here 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_role(self):
        """
        Returns the role of the user
        """
        return magic_method_to_check_role(self)
```

Then exactly like before you can do this

```
{% if user.get_role == 'administrator' %}
<div class="secret_div">
    Super Secret Information Here
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: {% if someFuntion(user, 'administrator')  %}blah{% endif %} - the question I am asking is how to accomplish calling functions from the template.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot call functions with parameters from Django templates. The best you can do is create a custom template tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/